# ComboBox Binding - Select correct value on form opening

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have the following in xaml. The textBlock displays my binding property correctly which is "AND" but how can I select it in the combo box?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CasualOperator}"/>
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding CasualOperator}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AND" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="OR" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AND NOT" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="OR NOT" />
 </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you want to achieve?

Comment: When my form opens, I want the combo box to select the right value which is "AND". Currently the items are there but nothing is selected

Comment: `AND` is value of `CasualOperator` property?

Comment: @RenDishen Yes. Please note my combobox items has "AND", "OR" etc

Comment: take a look here ,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx
 
i think your problem is that you use strings as the content for your combobox items

Comment: Just Set the `ComboBox.SelectedValue = 1;`

Comment: @prasy I have tried that. I changed my property of CasualOperator to int and hardcoded it to 1 so that binding gets value of 1 but the combo is still blank

Comment: @stsur If I change my property CasualOperator to int, how would the combo box work then?

Comment: @user2837961 you can change SelectedValue to SelectedIndex

Comment: @user2837961 Can you change the Binding to this. as you wanted TextBlock text to be selected in combobox `<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=TextBlock}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Add IsSelected="True" to the ComboBoxItem.

`<ComboBoxItem Content="AND" IsSelected="True" />`

Comment: I think he wants to select the ComboBox selected value by changing the value in the TextBlock